# Access the Places Connector via command line

Tags: command-line, lotus-notes

I have the [Quickr "Places Connector"](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/quickr/connectors/8.5.0/doc/qc850abd002/en_us/msconnectorhtml.html#task) installed on my machine which installs a connector very similar (  looks wise ) to webdav in Windows Explorer.

The path inside Windows Explorer is Places\Team Places\myProjectPath

I have tried to access this URL from the command line, but nothing works.

I tried

```
cd "Places\Team Places\myProjectPath"
cd /d "Places"
start "Places\Team Places\myProjectPath"
```

When I try to mount via the http url from command line or Windows Explorer I get "The drive could not be mapped because no network was found", though the site is up ( ping confirms that ).

"Places" also does not show when I list all the mounts with `wmic logicaldisk get caption` , I also tried to look at the mounts under cygwin, but "Places" does not show up there either.

Furthermore, when I right click on a file and look at the properties I see a custom ( ugly ) properties screen with the location of the file within MyProject.

When I click on 'MyProject' it only shows https://subdomain.domain.com

Comment: If you right click one of the files in that "Place" and look at the properties, doesn't it list the actual file location?

Comment: @techie007 : updated my question wrt your comment.